# How to pass PHP mail.log output to a script

Tags: php, email, logging

I'm logging all php mail output using the mail.log setting in php.ini. Rather than log to a file I want to have the log data sent to a script for parsing in real-time to raise alerts.

I have tried:
    mail.log="|/path/to/script.php"

in the hope that it might work like /etc/aliases, but that doesn't work. Any ideas greatly appreciated :-)

System is Postfix on Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use a wrapper for sendmail command, for example you can create a script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# file: sendmail-wrapper-php
# env vars: ${HTTP_HOST}, ${REMOTE_ADDR}, ${SCRIPT_NAME}, ${PWD}, ${UID}

# ....
# check and alert 

#send email.
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i $*
```

and `php_set_envs.php` to sets some PHP variables to the shell environment:

```php
<?php
putenv("HTTP_HOST=".@$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
putenv("SCRIPT_NAME=".@$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
putenv("SCRIPT_FILENAME=".@$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
putenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT=".@$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
putenv("REMOTE_ADDR=".@$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Now you force all customers to use this wrapper script instead of the original `/usr/sbin/sendmail` binary. Modify your `php.ini` and add/change:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail-wrapper-php
auto_prepend_file = /www/php/php_set_envs.php
```

Make sure it has correct access permissions:

```
$ chown root /usr/sbin/sendmail-wrapper-php
$ chmod 755 /usr/sbin/sendmail-wrapper-php
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I like that. I can modify it to work with Postfix instead of Sendmail, then do any processing I want either in bash in the wrapper, or in php in the set_envs. +1 for the putenv

Answer (score 0):

Use cron to execute a script that scan the mail.log file every minute.

```
//every minute 
* * * * * * php -f /path/to/script.php
```

I thing with this solution you have to use a database to remember scanned entries

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't really work for this case for two reasons. 1) needs to be real-time, not up to 1 minute delay. 2) don't want to parse the whole of that file each time, just the new entry.

I'm really after a way to redirect PHP log writing to a shell script, but might just be impossible. (Could have a file alteration listener running looking for appends to the file, but that's getting _really_ hacky)